# Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count error

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, semaphore

I am using the following code to access a local sql express database:

```
using (MessageBoxDbDataContext db = new MessageBoxDbDataContext())
{
    var msg = (from msgs in db.messages 
               where id == msgs.id select msgs).FirstOrDefault();

    if (msg == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
           string.Format("Message with id {0} was not found in db.", id));
    }

    msg.status = (int)status;
    msg.updated_at = DateTime.Now;

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Sometimes I get a "Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count" error on:

```
var msg = (from msgs in db.messages
           where id == msgs.id select msgs).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm trying to figure out why this might happen, if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Once we add “Pooling=False” condition to connection string then it will disable connection pool and run application without any problem